# Android: How to maintain backwards-compatibility?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, backwards-compatibility

According to the instructions found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), to make your app state which screen sizes you can support, you'll need to compile your app against Android 1.6.

Using the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion this should run also on Android 1.5:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" 
          android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

However, when I try to launch my app from Eclipse to run in a emulated 1.5, I get the following error:

```
 Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 1.6'.
```

Is this an error of the eclipse tools/emulator? Or how do I get it to also target 1.5 correctly while giving me the option to specify the supported screens?

Comment: Have you got the AVD running BEFORE you start the application?

Comment: @Peterdk i have minsdk=3 and tgtsdk=14, eclipse complains but going manual solves the issue, i just wanted to know if the marked would not complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force Eclipse/ADT to show you a list of all available targets and let you pick an older target by changing your debug and run configurations:

1. Select **Run > Debug Configurations...** (or Run Configurations)
2. In the left pane, select **Android Application > *(your project)***
3. Open the **Target** tab in the main view
4. For 'Deployment Target Selection Mode', choose **Manual**
5. Press **Apply**, then **Close**

Comment: Although it shows when running that AVD is incompatible, it does allow me to upload to the device and it runs correctly. Now hoping that on the market it will serve to 1.5 users.

Comment: This is a nice solution, although they really should just let you set it to choose older versions in run configurations and only give you a warning